# how to set one to many relation in nestjs graphql

Tags: graphql, nestjs

this is my relation user entity

```
@OneToMany(() => DoctorSchedule, doctorSchedule => doctorSchedule.user)
  @Field(type => DoctorSchedule)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "doctorId" })
  doctorSchedules?: DoctorSchedule[];
```

---

this is my resolver

```
@ResolveField((returns) => DoctorSchedule)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  doctorSchedules(@Parent() user: User): Promise<DoctorSchedule[]> {
    return this.usersService.getDoctorSchedule(user.id);
  }
```

---

this is my doctor schedule entity

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.doctorSchedules)
  @Field(type => User, { nullable: true })
  user?: User;
```

---

this is my rsollver doctor schedule

```
@ResolveField(returns => User)
  // @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  user(@Parent() doctorSchedule: DoctorSchedule): Promise<User> {
    return this.doctorScheduleService.getUser(doctorSchedule.doctorId);
  }
```

many to one relation is working like:

```
query{
  doctorSchedules{
    day
  }user(id:11){
    first_name
    last_name
  }
}
```

output is good

but  one to many is not working like:

```
query{
  user(id:11){
    email
    first_name
    doctorSchedules{
            day
    }
  }
}
```

its giver me error "Cannot return null for non-nullable field DoctorSchedule.day."
please help me

Comment: if you are using graphql only for the purpose of reducing dataset & nothing else.. then I would recommend you to checkout - https://github.com/restmap/restmap-node

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the relationship in your service

**Example:**

```
method() {    
return yourRepository.find({ relations: ['doctorSchedules'] });
}
```

Comment: resolve my issue `@OneToMany(() => DoctorSchedule, doctorSchedule => doctorSchedule.user)
  @Field(type => [DoctorSchedule])
  @JoinColumn({ name: "doctorId" })
  doctorSchedules?: DoctorSchedule[];` i hv just pass array in field type its working well